# ideavim x-mode insert mode completion

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

I recently watched a [youtube](https://youtu.be/3TX3kV3TICU?t=17m11s) video in which a guy showed how to use the Vim's X-mode (insert mode completion) to complete words or even whole lines depending on a context. It works great in Vim, but I tried to accomplish the same with PhpStorm/PyCharm, etc. with no luck.

Is it even possible to accomplish it with IdeaVim?

Answer (score 3):

IdeaVim doesn't have this mode. It allows you to use IDE's context sensitive completion for programming languages, but there is nothing context sensitive for natural languages. The only thing that comes somewhat close is [cyclic expand word](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/hippie-completion-cyclic-expanding-words.html).